# XPath search in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

I have the following XML stored in a SQL Server XML column. I want to select the rows using SQL SERVER xpath.

SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE XMLCol.exist('//Players/Player/FirstName/text()[contains(lower-case(.),"luis")]') = 1
```

Rather than using contains can I use something that compares exact value?

```
 <Players>
    <Player>
    <FirstName>Luis</FirstName>
    <LastName>Figo</LastName>
    </Player>
 </Players>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM TABLE 
 WHERE XMLCol.exist('//Players/Player/FirstName[text()[lower-case(.)="luis"]]') = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml `nodes()` method to extract your node values and compare your string something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
          id,
          xmlfield,
          pref.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') AS Names
    FROM test
    CROSS APPLY xmlfield.nodes('//Players/Player/FirstName') AS Names(pref)
    ) AS Result
WHERE Names = 'luis';
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43b87/6/0)

Comment: Too complicated, I think

Comment: @Backs Yeah, it probably appears so. But, the good thing about this solution is that you can do like search `easily` as opposed to OP's solution.

Comment: yep, I agree, your solution is mre common